# Gevent greenlet bubbling up exceptions to the parent

Tags: python, exception, gevent, greenlets

In using gevent, whenever a child greenlet throws an exception, I would like it to bubble up to the parent (and ideally have the parent throw the exception). In the documentation for greenlets, it says this is automatically done, but this doesn't appear to be the case in gevent.

How do I bubble up exceptions in gevent?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you [`link()`](https://www.gevent.org/api/gevent.greenlet.html#gevent.Greenlet.link) the child greenlet to the parent greenlet, then `LinkedExited` will be raised in the parent when the child exits. At that point you can check the `exception` property of the child greenlet. It will contain the exception instance raised in the child (if the child finished with an error). Now that you have the exception, you could handle it right away in the parent or you could raise it in the parent.

Comment: Just for reference and to save anyone skimming (this question has become the *top search result* for “do greenlet errors bubble”): this answer **only applies to gevent greenlets**; the "vanilla" `greenlet.greenlet` [always bubbles errors up to the parent](https://greenlet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/greenlet.html#uncaught-exceptions-are-raised-in-the-parent) \(if you want to *catch* the errors in that case, the parent has to enter a `try` clause before switching out.\)